# AS3 Key held down preventing mouse update

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-events

I'm developing a 3D game and I've noticed some odd behaviour when I hold down the movement keys; the game seems to temporarily ignore the mouse position and stops updating which way the player is facing. The game does not freeze - it's just as if it stops paying attention to the position of the mouse.

Here's the code I'm using to get key presses and releases:

```
public function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 32:
                        _keySpace = true;
                        break;
                case 81:
                        if (!keyQ) {
                            keyQ=true;
                        }
                        break;
                case 69:
                        if (!keyE) {
                            keyE=true;
                        }
                        break;
                case 65:
                        if (!keyA) {
                            keyA=true;
                        }
                        break;
                case 68:
                        if (!keyD) {
                            keyD=true;
                        }
                        break;

                case 87:
                        if (!keyW) {
                            keyW=true;
                        }
                        break;
                case 83:
                        if (!keyS) {
                            keyS=true;
                        }
                        break;
    }
}


public function keyLift(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (e.keyCode==32) {
                _keySpace = false;
            } else if (e.keyCode==81) {
                keyQ=false;
            } else if (e.keyCode==69) {
                keyE=false;
            } else if (e.keyCode==65) {
                keyA=false;
            } else if (e.keyCode==68) {
                keyD=false;
            } else if (e.keyCode==87) {
                keyW=false;
            } else if (e.keyCode==83) {
                keyS=false;
            }
        }
```

And the code to update the mouse position is just an ENTER_FRAME event:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
```

...that triggers the main game loop. Here's the relevant part that uses the mouse position. The mouseX and mouseY properties are used in Player to rotate the view left/right and up/down.

```
private function enterFrame(e:Event=null):void {
    _player.update(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

All of that works fine - it's just this problem with holding down the strafing keys; it's as if, once the key starts repeating, the game is taking all its time resolving those events and neglects to update the rotation - even though it's not dependent on a MouseEvent.

Does anyone know how to make Flash ignore repeating keys when the key is held down? Or is there some other problem?
Cheers.

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that it only has the above problem when tested from Flash; When run embedded in html it's fine. So I'll check if micapam's answer below works (and tick it, if it does) but I guess, otherwise, it's not a huge issue - just mildly irritating for the testing phase.

Comment: Actually, I've noticed that this IS happening in the html-embedded version. Anyone with any tips on how to prevent a KeyboardEvent firing every time? I'm not talking about altering the handler; I'd like to prevent held down key-repeats from firing the event to begin with. Has anyone else noticed this in their projects?

Comment: I'm not sure if this OK, but I thought I'd give this question a 'bump'. I'm STILL having held-down keys preventing mouse update (and ignoring mouse clicks) - but it seems to happen only once the keys are held down long enough to auto-repeat. Is there any way of preventing keys from auto-repeating in Flash? I'd really like to prevent needless events firing, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could check when your key handler was last triggered, and if it's more recently than a certain threshold, ignore it. You could make it a tenth of a second:

```
private static const KEY_THRESHOLD:int = 100; // 100 ms = 1/10 second

private static var lastPressedAt:int;

public function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    var now:int = new Date().getTime();

    if (lastPressedAt > 0 && now - lastPressedAt < KEY_THRESHOLD) {
        return;
    }

    lastPressedAt = now;

    // etc...
```

Comment: I tried this, as is, and it didn't work (int cannot be null); I've tried several variations of it too (using 'undefined' or changing lastPressedAt to a Number - the type returned by getTime()) - all without success. Any more tips?